# How do I test to see if a line of a .txt exists or not? and then raise and exception?

Tags: python

I've been working on a function for hours and I just can't see the solution since this is my first time working with opening .txt files, etc.

My function will open a .txt file of 50 names, with the first line (a header) being NAMES. And then it will create a list of those names. I need to test the function so if the line 'NAMES' is not in the txt file it will raise an exception. I have been working on the 'NAMES' part for longer than I care to admit and can't see what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
EOF = ''
def load_names(fName):
    global line, names
    print(end = f"Opening file {fName} ...")
    try:
        f = open(fName, 'r')
    except:
        raise Exception(f"OOPS! File {fName} not found")
    print(end = "reading...")
    line = f.readline().strip()     
    while line.strip() != 'NAMES':
        line = f.readline().strip()  
        while line != EOF and line.strip() != 'NAMES':
            raise Exception("!! Oops! Missing line 'NAMES' !!" )           
    names = []                             # To collect names from file
    line = f.readline().strip()            # Read in first name
    while line != EOF:
        if line =='\n': 
            print("!! Oops! Blank line not allowed !!")
        names.append(line.strip())
        line = f.readline()
    f.close()
    print(end = "closed.\n")
    return names
```

The 'blank line not allowed' works when tested, but the way I have this code written now, even If I open a file that does have the 'NAMES' line in it, it still gives the error  "Exception("!! Oops! Missing line 'NAMES' !!" )". I'm not sure how to do it, basically.

The files i am testing this with look like:

With NAMES -

```
NAMES
Mike
James
Anna
```

Without NAMES -

```
Mike
James 
Anna
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In your first line, is "Names" the only word? Or does the first line contain "NAMES Mike James Anna"?

Comment: it is only NAMES, the format is each of those words are on a different line

Comment: Could you please edit the question to put each name in a different line? It seems like all words are in the same line.

Comment: This is how I pasted your text file - https://pastebin.com/G6JBHtMN.
When I ran your funtion, the output is "Opening file foo.txt ...reading...closed.".

Comment: yes the way you have it on your link is how the txt files are formatted. trying to figure out how to edit my question to show that.

Comment: When I run your code with the given file structure, it does not throw the error you mentioned. The output is what I mentioned in my previous comment. Can you check if you are reading from the right file?

Comment: Yes i have 2 files I am using to test the function with, one is with NAMES and one without as you edited the question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function seems much too complex, and the exception handling is wrong. For example, it will replace a "permission denied" exception with a generic `Exception` with an incorrect message saying the file wasn't found, even though that was not the reason for the error.

Instead, probably

- avoid the use of global variables;
- don't trap errors you can't meaningfully handle;
- don't `strip()` more than once - save the stripped value so you can use it again;
- simply read one line at a time, and check that it passes all your criteria.

```py
def load_names(fName):
    with open(fName, 'r') as f:
        seen_names = False
        names = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line == 'NAMES':
                seen_names = True
            elif line == '':
                raise Exception("!! Oops! Blank line not allowed !!")
            else:
                names.append(line)
        if not seen_names:
            raise Exception("!! Oops! Missing line 'NAMES' !!" )
    return names
```

If you actually want `NAMES` to be the first line in the file, it's not hard to change the code to require that instead. Maybe then it does make sense to read the first line separately before the loop.

```py
def load_names(fName):
    with open(fName, 'r') as f:
        seen_names = False
        names = []
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if not seen_names:
                if line == 'NAMES':
                    seen_names = True
                else:
                    raise Exception("!! Oops! Missing line 'NAMES' !!" )
            elif line == '':
                raise Exception("!! Oops! Blank line not allowed !!")
            else:
                names.append(line)
    return names
```

Concretely, the bug in your original attempt is that the code continues to read lines until it gets one which doesn't contain `NAMES`, and then complains.

Comment: when I use the functions you posted here @tripleee, with txt file that does have NAMES in the top line, it still raises the exception Missing line NAMES, instead of just returning the list of names.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use this and modify it slightly to get what I needed